# how to backup 2 sources with rsync to different destination

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

I didn't manage to find the solution to my need.
I'd like to backup two different sources in one command with rsync with an historic.
for example I have 2 sources :

```
/home/docker/
/var/volumes/
```

and the destination structure i'd like to have:

```
/backup
  /docker 
    /day1
    /day2
    /latest
  /volumes
    /day1
    /day2
    /latest
```

I tried with a previous bash script I use regularly and adapt it but it does not do what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +%y%m%d-%Hh%Mm%Ss)
BKP_DIR=/mnt/backup
BKP_SRC01=/home/pi/docker
BKP_SRC02=/var/lib/docker/volumes
SNAPSHOT=${BKP_DIR}/$(NOW)
LATEST=${BKP_DIR}/latest

rsync                               \
    --verbose                       \
    --progress                      \
    --human-readable                \
    --archive                       \
    --delete                        \
    --backup                        \
    --backup-dir=${SNAPSHOT}        \
    --log-file=${BKP_DIR}/${NOW}-rsync.log \
${BKP_SRC01}/${BKP_SRC02}/ ${LATEST}/
```

Comment: You can't have multiple destinations in the rsync command - it only works from point to point. You need to run rsync two times for two destinations.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does "an historic mean"?  Why 1 command? Why does it have to be rsync?  I posit you may want to use rsnapshot which cleverly does versioning using symlinks, has a config file so you can back up multiple paths/trees and usrs rsync as the backend transfer mechanism.